# How to find a particular word starting with given string in a line in JAVA

Tags: string, java-7

Input1 : This is introductory information of new word search engine

Input2 : in

Output : {introductory, information}

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify if this solves your problem:

```
package q46379748;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindWord {

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
        String input = "This is introductory information of new word search engine";

        String query = "in";

        String[ ] result = new FindWord( ).findWords( input, query );

        for ( String s : result ) {
            System.out.println( s );
        }
    }

    private String[ ] findWords( String input, String query ) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\b" + query + "\\w*\\b" );

        Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

        List< String > v = new ArrayList<>( );
        while ( m.find( ) ) {
            v.add( m.group( ) );
        }

        return v.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );
    }

}
```

Notice that this solution uses Regular Expression (RegEx) and the created pattern is `\bin\w+\b`, where:

- `\b` means word boundary
- `\w` means word characters
- `*` means zero or more (any quantity) of the previous item, in this case the `\w`

Keep in mind that it would be better to change the query to be a RegEx query:

```
String query = "\\bin\\w*\\b";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( query );
```

If you want to learn RegEx, there's plenty of material out there:

https://regexone.com/

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

http://www.rexegg.com/